# Extend Int enum with comparison operators

Tags: swift, enums, integer, compare, extension-methods

Very often you have Int enums like this:

```
enum Difficulty: Int {
    case Easy = 0
    case Normal
    case Hard
}
```

`Difficulty` values have a certain meaning and we may want to introduce order for them. For example, somewhere we need to compare:

```
let isBonusAvailable = level.difficulty.rawVAlue <= Difficulty.Hard.rawValue
```

I want to make this code a little bit shorter:

```
let isBonusAvailable = level.difficulty <= .Hard
```

It **can** be easily achieved if I add `<=` directly to the `Difficulty`. But I wanted to solve this problem in general, so I tried this super-tricky way:

```
protocol RawRepresentableByInt {
    var rawValue: Int { get }
}

extension RawRepresentableByInt {
    static func <(lhs: RawRepresentableByInt, rhs: RawRepresentableByInt) -> Bool {
        return lhs.rawValue < rhs.rawValue
    }

    static func >(lhs: RawRepresentableByInt, rhs: RawRepresentableByInt) -> Bool {
        return lhs.rawValue > rhs.rawValue
    }

    static func <=(lhs: RawRepresentableByInt, rhs: RawRepresentableByInt) -> Bool {
        return lhs.rawValue <= rhs.rawValue
    }

    static func >=(lhs: RawRepresentableByInt, rhs: RawRepresentableByInt) -> Bool {
        return lhs.rawValue >= rhs.rawValue
    }
}

// Error: Extension of protocol 'RawRepresentable' cannot have an inheritance clause
extension RawRepresentable: RawRepresentableByInt where RawValue == Int  {
}
```

It produces a compiler error:

> Error: Extension of protocol 'RawRepresentable' cannot have an inheritance clause

I think there is nothing unimplementable in comparison of `Int` `enum` in term of logic. Please, help me to trick the Swift compiler. Anyone, who also need such extensions may participate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was easier than I thought. So, basically you can use `Self` instead of creating an additional protocol.

```
enum Difficulty: Int {
    case Easy = 0
    case Normal
    case Hard
}

extension RawRepresentable where RawValue: Comparable {
    static func <(lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Bool {
        return lhs.rawValue < rhs.rawValue
    }

    static func >(lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Bool {
        return lhs.rawValue > rhs.rawValue
    }

    static func <=(lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Bool {
        return lhs.rawValue <= rhs.rawValue
    }

    static func >=(lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Bool {
        return lhs.rawValue >= rhs.rawValue
    }
}

let easy = Difficulty.Easy
print(easy > .Hard) // false
```

Comment: Instead of `where RawValue == Int` you can use `where RawValue: Comparable` and thus autogenerate comparison operators for all `Comparable` raw types (`Int` included).

Comment: `Comparable` is nice, thanks for it. But auto-generation doesn't work in this case, because it's the `RawValue` who's comparable, not the enumeration.